# Firebase http put request in a for loop

Tags: javascript, json, http, firebase-realtime-database, put

I am using firebase's realtime database and trying to send  a put request in a for loop, my code is as follows:

```
var httpput = function(articleIdlol, versionnumber){
  $http({
      method: "PUT",
        url: FirebaseUrl +articleIdlol+ "/versions/" +versionnumber+"/moment.json",
        data: document.getElementById("changeMoment").value
   });
}

$scope.changeMomentorSituation = function(articleId){
for (var x = 0; x < $scope.articlesData[articleId].versions.length; x++){
    httpput(articleId, x);
}
}
```

$scope.articlesData contains response.data from an earlier http get request to the firebase database. articleId is a2, I have checked.

I can assure you that the link to the database is correct. However, when I run the code, I am getting a 400 (Bad Request) Error which may mean that the data I am sending is in an incorrect format.

I believe I am sending a string but to be sure I converted the data to a string first and sent it but I get the same error. 'moment' is a key in an object which is contained in an Array called 'versions'.

Here is the JSON schema:

```
  "EditedArticles" : {
"a2" : {
  "versions" : [ {
    "answer" : "a2",
    "article_code" : "a2",
    "created_time" : "2016-08-12T01:20:14.300Z",
    "datatype" : "article",
    "hashtags" : [ "a2", "a2", "a2" ],
    "keyword" : "a2",
    "moment" : "a2",
    "question" : "a2",
    "seo" : {
      "description" : "a2",
      "og_title" : "a2",
      "title" : "a2"
    },
    "situation" : "a2",
    "title" : "a2",
    "version" : 1
  }
 }
```

I tried sending {moment: "xxx"} but this nested another key moment in moment(original) with the value "xxx". This means that, I can use the earlier data and recreate every field in a new object and send it in the data field in the http put request under:

```
FirebaseUrl +articleIdlol+ "/versions/" +versionnumber.json
```

but shouldn't I be able to send a single string to modify the value of the key moment assuming that my URL path is correct?

Comment: _"Error which may mean that the data I am sending is in an incorrect format"_ Check it in console -> Network-tab

Comment: "Invalid data; couldn't parse JSON object, array, or value. Perhaps you're using invalid characters in your key names." is what I am seeing. But I have checked the type of data I am sending and it is a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, luckily and thoughtfully, Firebase has a http request called PATCH that does exactly what I required. Please refer to: https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/guide/saving-data.html

As for my solution, here it is:

```
var httpput = function(articleIdlol, versionnumber){
  $http({
        url: FirebaseUrl +articleIdlol+ "/versions/" +versionnumber+".json",
        method: "PATCH",
        data: {"moment":document.getElementById("changeMoment").value}
   });
}

$scope.changeMomentorSituation = function(article){
for (var x = 0; x < $scope.articlesData[article].versions.length; x++){
    httpput(article, x);
}
}
```

Observe that if I had used a PUT request as I mentioned, if the URL was

```
FirebaseUrl +articleIdlol+ "/versions/" +versionnumber+ ".json"
```

The entire object with 12 keys would be replaced with {moment: "xxx"} BUT if you amend it to a **PATCH** method request, with the same URL and data fields in the http request, the key 'moment' is updated with the data. Really. This was all.